# How to get windows session name?

Tags: c, windows, session

Windows has a  cmd "[**query session**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490800.aspx)", it displays information about sessions on a terminal server, include "sessionname".

I want to use **Windows API**------**LsaEnumerateLogonSessions** and **LsaGetLogonSessionData**       to get these session information like this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    ULONG count = 0;
    PLUID list = NULL;
    PSECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA data;

    LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(&count, &list);
    for (i = 0; i < (int)count; i++)
    {
            LsaGetLogonSessionData(&list[i], &data);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can get a **SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA** struct:

```
typedef struct _SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA {
  ULONG                     Size;
  LUID                      LogonId;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        UserName;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        LogonDomain;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        AuthenticationPackage;
  ULONG                     LogonType;
  ULONG                     Session;
  PSID                      Sid;
  LARGE_INTEGER             LogonTime;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        LogonServer;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        DnsDomainName;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        Upn;
  ULONG                     UserFlags;
  LSA_LAST_INTER_LOGON_INFO LastLogonInfo;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        LogonScript;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        ProfilePath;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        HomeDirectory;
  LSA_UNICODE_STRING        HomeDirectoryDrive;
  LARGE_INTEGER             LogoffTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER             KickOffTime;
  LARGE_INTEGER             PasswordLastSet;
  LARGE_INTEGER             PasswordCanChange;
  LARGE_INTEGER             PasswordMustChange;
} SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA, *PSECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA;
```

But it does not contain a **sessionname**!

Any idea on how to get the "sessonname"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this answer is helpful to you, wbm, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer so others may more easily find it in the future.

Comment: You're confusing logon sessions with Remote Desktop (aka terminal services) sessions.  They're two entirely different beasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "session name" is called the "winstation name" in the API docs (very confusingly, because it  is definitely not a Window Station, as the docs [apologize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

[`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(WTSWinStationName)` will get it for you using the standard WTS functions.

I'm not sure why you're using `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions`, because it will return not only sessions, but any logon, including network logins that haven't created sessions. If you have some particular reason for needing the LUID, you'll have to filter the list, pick out those where the Session member is non-zero, then do a `WTSQuerySessionInformation` on that to get the winstation name. Or, you could filter for all the logons where LogonType is one of the four interactive types. It's also possible even on Vista and later for the console to be on session 0, and this is normal on XP, so remember also to check for session 0 and `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` to make sure you've included on your list all the sessions you're interested in. It's going to be much simpler I suspect just to use the [`WTSEnumerateSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function!

Answer (score 0):

WTSEnumerateSessions or WTSQuerySessionInformation